# How to draw Decoder (Add in/out pins)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I'm new in Latex, I try to draw an decoder and I don't know how to add the inputs/outputs (like the image).

- Decoder 2:4
- 2 inputs
- 4 outputs

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{circuitikz,siunitx}
  \usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{circuitikz}[circuit logic IEC] 

  \node[
        and gate,
        inputs={nnn},
        and gate IEC symbol={},
        text height=5cm,
        text width=2cm,
       ] (A) {};

   (A.in 1) node [anchor=east] {A}     %not working
   (A.in 2) node [anchor=east] {B}     %not working

  \end{circuitikz}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433568/how-to-draw-circuit-logic-align-the-outputs) and the answer giving there. What did you try?  explain where the problem lies.

Comment: It is good that you admit that it is for a homework, thanks for your honesty. But if it's for your homework you should really show some effort. Take a look at the link @albert posted and try to accomplish what you need. If you face issues while doing so, you can ask a question about that specific issue with the code you got so far. As of now you might not get any or many answers.

Comment: @Skillmon it isn't a Latex home work. it's just me who want to use Latex. What I m asking for is just the code to draw the same drawing in the image.

Comment: Honestly, this is not a *draw this for me for free* service.

Comment: @albert It isn't a problem to solve, but rather how to draw this circuit. I solved this problem I have just to write the answer in Latex.

Comment: See comment from Johannes_B and Skillmon

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Nothing appears? The wrong thing appears? You get an error? (Which error?)

Comment: You're mixing `circuitikz` and the built-in circults libraries. See the Ti*k*Z manual for examples. But an 'and' gate has a single output - not four. So what do you want exactly?

Comment: None of the logic gates support multiple outputs, so you want something which isn't a logic gate or you want something with a single output or you want something not supported by these libraries.

Comment: It is really not reasonable to change questions in ways which invalidate existing answers. Your edit does not quite do this, but it means that my answer is now at best a partial one, whereas it fully addressed the original question. Please roll back, read the docs, have a go and post a new question with your attempt if you need help using the logic circuits libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `circuitikz` with the `circuits` libraries bundled with Ti*k*Z itself. The logic gates can handle multiple inputs, if you follow the examples in the Ti*k*Z manual, but not multiple outputs. They are, after all, logic gates. (And I don't think Ti*k*Z knows about fuzzy logics or quantum logical states.)

However, you can draw a block with lines going in and out of it very easily using Ti*k*Z itself.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    draw,
    text height=5cm,
    text width=2cm,
  ] (A) {};
  \foreach \i in {60,30,-30,-60}
    \draw (A.\i) -- ++(1,0);
  \foreach \i in {-120,120}
      \draw (A.\i) -- ++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: block with inputs & outputs: basic Ti*k*Z]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One last thing how can I add an OR gate to the outputs? check the update image (second image).

Comment: @AdilBlanco The Ti*k*Z manual shows you how to add logic gates. Please try to modify an example there. I answered one question. You are now asking a different question about a library which I do not personally use. The documentation is not long, however, and looks to be straightforward, so I suggest reading it. If you still have trouble, post a new question showing what you've tried (and linking this question if appropriate).